# Getters, Setters, Constructors and their parameters

Tags: java, constructor, setter, getter

Ye've been very helpful so far even though I havn't been great at wording my questions. I think I almost know what I'm doing but I'm trying to get my head around the relationship between getters, setters and constructors. I have two classes as follows
`Student` and `Name` and I'm confused about the relationship between the parameters in the getters and setters and constructor

If I remove the parameters from the Name constructor, i.e. this

```
public Name (){
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
```

and aslo edited the Student constructor to reflect this

```
public Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String street, String area, String city, String country, int age, char gender, String college, String course,  int level, int gradePointAverage){ //This is the list of variables called from the Student class
this.id = id;
this.name = new Name(); //I have removed the parameters here
this.name.setFirstName(firstName);
this.name.setLastName(lastName);
this.address = new Address(street, area, city, country);
this.age = age;
this.gender = gender;
this.college = college;
this.course = course;
this.level = level;
this.gradePointAverage = gradePointAverage;
```

}

I'm not sure what impact it would have. I would be very greatful of someone could explain to me where I should/shouldn't have parameters and why? Understand this concept is what is holding me back from moving any further with coding at the moment.

```
public class Student {
    private Name name; // This is calling from the Name class, giving it the name 'name'
    private Address address; // This calls from Address, giving it the name 'address'

    private char gender;

    private String course, college;

    private int gradePointAverage, id, age, level;

    public Student(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String street, String area, String city, String country, int age, char gender, String college, String course,  int level, int gradePointAverage){ //This is the list of variables called from the Student class
        this.id = id;
        this.name = new Name(firstName, lastName);
        //this.name = new Name();
        this.name.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.name.setLastName(lastName);
        this.address = new Address(street, area, city, country);
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.college = college;
        this.course = course;
        this.level = level;
        this.gradePointAverage = gradePointAverage;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name.toString();
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address.toString();
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public char getGender(){
        return gender;
    }

    public String getCollege(){
        return college;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

     public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public int getGradePointAverage() {
        return gradePointAverage;
    }

    public void printStudent() {
        System.out.println("The Student " + name.toString() + " is logged under the student ID number " + id + ".");
        System.out.println("They live at " + address.toString() + " and their age is " + age + ".");
        System.out.println("Their gender is " + gender + ".");
        System.out.println("The student studies at " + college + " attending classes in " + course + ".");
        System.out.println("Their level is " + level + " and the student grade average in points is " + gradePointAverage + ".");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

and `Name`

```
public class Name{

private String firstName, lastName;

public Name (String firstName, String lastName){
//public Name (){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName){
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

//public String getFirstName() {
//  return firstName;
//}

//public String getLastName() {
//  return lastName;
//}

///** Returns first name concatenated to last name */
//public String toString() {
//  return firstName + " " + lastName;
//}

}
```

Comment: @BharatSinha This is bad advice. There is positively no need to define a default constructor, except when using Hibernate and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `constructors` are for initialization of an instance of an Object to ensure that all the minimum amount of data required for a `valid` object state are provided at creation time.

In your case `Name` should have a `constructor` that requires `firstName` and `lastName` because those things are what make the `Name` object fully initialized. This Object should work just like your `Address` object you have shown as well.

Otherwise if you use `setXXX` methods, the `Name` object is incomplete with the two `String` objects initialized to `null` or some other undefined state.

Comment: Thanks. So whether the initial values are what I want isn't really important in terms of a valid instance being initiated. I can use getters and setters to change the *initial* value into a *correct* value.

Comment: The "initial values" are more appropriately called *instance variables/fields*.  Getters are used to get the instance fields, and setters are used to mutate these field's values.  In short, you *can* use setters to mutate the instance variables to hold "correct" values.